# Using online mysql hosting server

Tags: php, android, mysql

I don't want to jump into this without having a good idea how to approach this.

**What I've done**

I have set up a mysql server on `000webhost.com` .  I have successfully created a database and a table within that database.

I have also added one entry into this table.

This all worked successfully and I was provided with the following information from the 000webhost:

```
$server = "mysql17.000webhost.com";
$user = "a5032812_stfback";
$pass = "*******";
$db = "a5032812_dencal";
$conn = mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments VALUES(....)";
```

So I added this into a php file.

**What I want to do**

I will have an android app with an EditText field. I want the user to input a comment and it is stored into this online mysql database.

**Where I'm confused**

I have successfully done this using a local server and a website. Now I have an online server and an android.

So I need to connect to the php file through my android (i.e - in the android code). Then I run the php file from android and it will insert data into the database? Am I right? If so, I'll research myself how to connect to the php file. I'm used to using `post` from html commands, I'm sure it is different in Android.

Secondly, where will this php file be located. It was in my `www`  folder in my local server in WAMP. Now I have an online server and have no idea where to store it. Also I have no idea how to access it.

Also, why do I need to provide server information in the php file if it is located on the server? IF. Shouldnt it be obvious where it is?

Mainly I'm not sure how to access this php file from android.

I don't need code as much as I need an overall understanding of this concept in general. I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can not directly communicate with `MySQL` database from `android app`. For that you need to create web services in `PHP`. And calling those methods from android you can access to the database.

After creating webservices you need to call that `URL` from your android app. You can use `AsyncTask` for that or you can use third party plugins something like [OkHTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) or [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) or [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the PHP file is simply a link on the internet which I access through providing Android with that URL, am I right? Can I also host this on 000webhost?? I am familiar with AsyncTask already from parsing some realtime API, so I think I might manage that.

Comment: @GregoryPeck: Yes. Exactly. you need to parse that `php` URL in `AsyncTask`. One more thing, if you are accessing your app from your phone then you need to have your PHP project on server. That means, you can not call local host project from your phone. Make sure your URL gives appropriate response in `JSOP` OR `XML` and that response you can easily parse in android.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. One last question. I have been looking through 000webhost.com and can't seem to find a link to host my php file. Is it possible that 000webhost don't provide this. If so is there another free php hosting website available. And can I access my mysql database from a php file located anywhere on the internet?

Comment: It depends on your hosting provider. I never used `000webhost.com`. But, I guess they have free `PHP` hosting. You can use basic hosting on `GoDaddy` or `Windows Azure` as well.